# MySql stored function throws no errors but returns no output can't debug it

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I wrote a recursive function to traverse a hierarchy in one of our tables.  It simply returns an integer at the root of the hierarchy.  Here is the code:

```
USE `RevMatic_Viafield`;
DROP function IF EXISTS `getGroupProductCategory`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `RevMatic_Viafield`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`sync_talend`@`%` FUNCTION `getGroupProductCategory`(pIdProductCategory INT(11)) RETURNS int(11)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
  DECLARE lIdProductCategory INT(11);

  SELECT idParentProductCategory INTO lIdProductCategory
    FROM Prod_ProductCategories
    WHERE idProductCategory = pIdProductCategory
  ;

  IF lIdProductCategory IS NULL THEN
    RETURN (pIdProductCategory);
  ELSE 
    SET lIdProductCategory = getGroupProductCategory(lIdProductCategory);
  END IF;

  RETURN (lIdProductCategory);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This appears to compile and run without errors, but it doesn't return anything either, not even null:

```
SELECT RevMatic_Viafield.getGroupProductCategory(93);
```

and

```
SELECT RevMatic_Viafield.getGroupProductCategory(93)
  FROM DUAL
;
```

do not return a result set.  The action output in MySql Workbench shows OK in the response column.  I Can't seem to get any kind of debugging statements into the code. How do I debug this and where is my result set.  I'm expecting one row with one column in the result set that has either a null or an integer in the column.

Comment: Why the parenthesis around variables you are trying to return?

Comment: Mike, I guess on any given day, I'm writing code in between six and ten different languages, some of them require the parenthesis and some don't.  I'm getting old and sometimes forget where I'm coding. :) With or without, the result is the same.